# Problem with custom browser opened from powershell

Tags: function, powershell, user-interface, button, textbox

In my GUI I have a button which opens a custom-created browser of AD (something like the left panel of dsa.msc). I created a button to open it and I want to display the selected path in a textbox next to the button. I have two problems, one small, one major. The small problem is, that the browser opens automatically before the GUI itself (but that's just a nuisance, nothing serious and I can even pretend that it was meant to work like that :-) ). The bigger, major problem is, that when I click on the button from the GUI and select another path than that already in the textbox from the initial opening, the path doesn't change. The OK button in the browser works more like Cancel. This is how the textbox is defined:

```
$Location_val                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Location_val.multiline          = $false
$Location_val.text               = Browse-AD
$Location_val.width              = 250
$Location_val.height             = 20
$Location_val.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,160)
```

This is the definition of the function creating the browser:

```
function Browse-AD()
{
    # original inspiration: https://itmicah.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/active-directory-ou-picker-in-powershell/
    # author: Rene Horn the.rhorn@gmail.com

<#
    Copyright (c) 2015, Rene Horn
    All rights reserved.

    Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

    1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#>

    $dc_hash = @{}
    $selected_ou = $null

    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $forest = Get-ADForest

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

    function Get-NodeInfo($sender, $dn_textbox)
    {
        $selected_node = $sender.Node
        $dn_textbox.Text = $selected_node.Name
    }

    function Add-ChildNodes($sender)
    {
        $expanded_node = $sender.Node

        if ($expanded_node.Name -eq "root") {
            return
        }

        $expanded_node.Nodes.Clear() | Out-Null

        $dc_hostname = $dc_hash[$($expanded_node.Name -replace '(OU=[^,]+,)*((DC=\w+,?)+)','$2')]

        $child_OUs = Get-ADObject -Server $dc_hostname -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "organizationalUnit" -or ObjectClass -eq "container"' -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase $expanded_node.Name

        if($child_OUs -eq $null) {
            $sender.Cancel = $true
        } else {
            foreach($ou in $child_OUs) {
                $ou_node = New-Object Windows.Forms.TreeNode
                $ou_node.Text = $ou.Name
                $ou_node.Name = $ou.DistinguishedName
                $ou_node.Nodes.Add('') | Out-Null
                $expanded_node.Nodes.Add($ou_node) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }

    function Add-ForestNodes($forest, [ref]$dc_hash)
    {
        $ad_root_node = New-Object Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $ad_root_node.Text = $forest.RootDomain
        $ad_root_node.Name = "root"
        $ad_root_node.Expand()

        $i = 1
        foreach ($ad_domain in $forest.Domains) {
            Write-Progress -Activity "Querying AD forest for domains and hostnames..." -Status $ad_domain -PercentComplete ($i++ / $forest.Domains.Count * 100)

            $dc = Get-ADDomainController -Server $ad_domain
            $dn = $dc.DefaultPartition
            $dc_hash.Value.Add($dn, $dc.Hostname)
            $dc_node = New-Object Windows.Forms.TreeNode
            $dc_node.Name = $dn
            $dc_node.Text = $dc.Domain
            $dc_node.Nodes.Add("") | Out-Null
            $ad_root_node.Nodes.Add($dc_node) | Out-Null
        }

        return $ad_root_node
    }

    $main_dlg_box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $main_dlg_box.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,600)
    $main_dlg_box.MaximizeBox = $false
    $main_dlg_box.MinimizeBox = $false
    $main_dlg_box.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'

    # widget size and location variables
    $ctrl_width_col = $main_dlg_box.ClientSize.Width/20
    $ctrl_height_row = $main_dlg_box.ClientSize.Height/15
    $max_ctrl_width = $main_dlg_box.ClientSize.Width - $ctrl_width_col*2
    $max_ctrl_height = $main_dlg_box.ClientSize.Height - $ctrl_height_row
    $right_edge_x = $max_ctrl_width
    $left_edge_x = $ctrl_width_col
    $bottom_edge_y = $max_ctrl_height
    $top_edge_y = $ctrl_height_row

    # setup text box showing the distinguished name of the currently selected node
    $dn_text_box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    # can not set the height for a single line text box, that's controlled by the font being used
    $dn_text_box.Width = (14 * $ctrl_width_col)
    $dn_text_box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($left_edge_x, ($bottom_edge_y - $dn_text_box.Height))
    $main_dlg_box.Controls.Add($dn_text_box)
    # /text box for dN

    # setup Ok button
    $ok_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $ok_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($ctrl_width_col * 2), $dn_text_box.Height)
    $ok_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($right_edge_x - $ok_button.Width), ($bottom_edge_y - $ok_button.Height))
    $ok_button.Text = "Ok"
    $ok_button.DialogResult = 'OK'
    $main_dlg_box.Controls.Add($ok_button)
    # /Ok button

    # setup tree selector showing the domains
    $ad_tree_view = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    $ad_tree_view.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($max_ctrl_width, ($max_ctrl_height - $dn_text_box.Height - $ctrl_height_row*1.5))
    $ad_tree_view.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($left_edge_x, $top_edge_y)
    $ad_tree_view.Nodes.Add($(Add-ForestNodes $forest ([ref]$dc_hash))) | Out-Null
    $ad_tree_view.Add_BeforeExpand({Add-ChildNodes $_})
    $ad_tree_view.Add_AfterSelect({Get-NodeInfo $_ $dn_text_box})
    $main_dlg_box.Controls.Add($ad_tree_view)
    # /tree selector

    $main_dlg_box.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

    return  $dn_text_box.Text
}
```

And this is the definition of the button that opens the browser:

```
$Select_AD_path                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Select_AD_path.Text             = "Browse..."
$Select_AD_path.Width            = 100
$Select_AD_path.Height           = 30
$Select_AD_path.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90,155)
$Select_AD_path.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Select_AD_path.add_Click(${function:Browse-AD})
```

How can I better achieve what I want? At best I'd like to open the GUI with some predefined value in the textbox, which I could change if needed by using the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes are required, to solve both issues:

- Change the initial value of the `$Location_val`:

```
$Location_val.text = ""
```

- Change the click event handler:

```
$Select_AD_path.add_Click({
    $dn = Browse-AD
    if ($dn) 
    {
        $Location_val.Text = $dn
    }
})
```

- Change the last lines of the Browse-AD function:

```
...
    if ($main_dlg_box.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Ok)
    {
        return $dn_text_box.Text
    }

    return $null
}
```